# Is this controller untestable?

Tags: .net, unit-testing

In its present state I dont think I can test it because of the dependencies on user authentication **(user.identity)** and route data **(RouteData.Values)**, original plan was to check if it was returning a view. Should I try to mock/fake these values or not be testing a controller like this in first place?

```html
public IActionResult Index()
{

 BlogHomeVM vm = new BlogHomeVM();

 int skip = int.TryParse((string)this.RouteData.Values["skip"], out skip) ? skip : 0;
 int showPosts = 3;

 vm.PageTitle = "Async and wait";

 vm.totalPosts = _context.Posts.Where(y => y.PublishedFrom <= DateTime.Now).Count();

 vm.Posts = _context.Posts
 .Where(y => y.PublishedFrom <= DateTime.Now || User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
 .OrderByDescending(x => x.DatePublished)
 .Skip(skip)
 .Take(showPosts)
 .ToList();

 vm.AllCats  = _context.PostCategory.ToList();
 vm.PageName = "Blog";
 vm.skip = skip;
 vm.showPosts = showPosts;

 return View(vm);
}
```

Comment: You question is basically "should I test this code". The answer is pretty much opinion based so I'm voting to close it as such.

Comment: Are there rules/suggestions around which parts of the code are suitable for testing and which type, ie unit,integration, system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can inject `IHttpContextAccessor` into your controller and use `_httpContext.GetRouteData()` and `_httpContext.User` to make it testable.

Read this article to understand what to test and how to write testable code - https://www.toptal.com/qa/how-to-write-testable-code-and-why-it-matters

Comment: Seems little bid odd injecting `IHttpContextAccessor`, because controller already have access to the current `HttpContext`

Comment: @Fabio not odd at all, you inject it so you can mock it later. You cannot mock `HttpContext` property.

Comment: I don't need to mock `HttpContext`, instead I can create it and inject to the controller. Possible I will need to mock `IIdentity` to provide expected value for  `IsAuthenticated`.